# How can I setup network traffic alerts on a Linux machine using Prometheus?

Tags: linux, networking, prometheus, alert, prometheus-node-exporter

I am using Prometheus to monitor network traffic on Linux machines. I see several useful metrics like `node_network_receive_bytes_total`, `node_network_transmit_bytes_total`, and `node_network_receive_errs_total`. How can I setup alerts for network traffic when I am not aware of the network bandwidth of the machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use some of queries to have good results of network monitoring.
i am using some queries on Grafana and i share them with you:

1. popular queries:

> **Query-outbound** `sum (irate(node_network_transmit_bytes{hostname=~"$hostname", device!~"lo|bond[0-9]|cbr[0-9]|veth.*"}[1m])) by (hostname) > 0`
>
> **Legend format**: {{hostname}} - {{device}} - outbound
>
> **Query-inbound** `sum (irate(node_network_receive_bytes{hostname=~"$hostname", device!~"lo|bond[0-9]|cbr[0-9]|veth.*"}[1m])) by (hostname)  > 0`
>
> **Legend format**: {{hostname}} - {{device}} - inbound

2. complicated queries:

**network terafic of eno(or any things you want) devices:**

> **Legend format:** `{{hostname}} - ({{device}})_in`
>
> irate(node_network_receive_bytes{hostname=~'$hostname',device=~"^en.*"}[5m])*8
>
> **Legend format:** `{{hostname}} - ({{device}})_out`
>
> irate(node_network_transmit_bytes{hostname=~'$hostname',device=~"^en.*"}[5m])*8

**netstas:**

> **Legend format:** `{{hostname}} established`
>
> node_netstat_Tcp_CurrEstab{hostname=~'$hostname'}

**udp stat:**

> irate(node_netstat_Udp_InDatagrams{hostname=~"$hostname"}[5m])
>
> irate(node_netstat_Udp_InErrors{hostname=~"$hostname"}[5m])
>
> irate(node_netstat_Udp_OutDatagrams{hostname=~"$hostname"}[5m])
>
> irate(node_netstat_Udp_NoPorts{hostname=~"$hostname"}[5m])

**contract**

> **Legend format:** `Queue Used ({{hostname}})`
>
> node_nf_conntrack_entries{hostname=~"$hostname"}/node_nf_conntrack_entries_limit{hostname=~"$hostname"}

pleas attention to hostname . it is a template variable on Grafan . and legend format is a label parsing for metrics on Grafana.