# Monitor External traffic of pod or service

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress, network-traffic, kubernetes-nodeport

I want to monitor external transmit and receive traffics of pod. External traffic means traffic that send or receive from outside of k8s cluster.

For example NodePort, LoadBalancer and ingress types of service.
I have `container_network_receive_bytes_total` and `container_network_transmit_bytes_total` in Prometheus metrics but I can't seprate internal and external traffic with them. I also used [k8spacket](https://github.com/k8spacket/k8spacket) but It did not satisfy my need.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to get the information you need is to install tcpdump in your Pod and exploit its potential.

If you don't want to dirty your application, you can think of creating a management Deployment where you install the tools you need to manage this type of request and connect to that.

I don't know which provider you have installed Kubernetes on, but there are very vertical documentations on the subject -->

OpenShift: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4569211

Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/packet-capture-pod-level

https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/capture-packets-kubernetes-ksniff

Comment: I want monitor all pods external network usage and I want automate this job because I want to set alert and trigger for that and implement some action for that

Comment: Ok, so you mean how much traffic goes in and out of the cluster. Take a look to this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46369624/21404450